# I am trying to check 25 boxes with random numbers and only be able to click each box if another one was already clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small game. The point of the game is, you get random numbers, and you need to click those numbers in order from 1 through 25.

Basically i want to make sure that i can only click on no. 2 if not 1 was clicked and i can't click on another other box. Once no. 1 and 2 have been clicked, i can only click on no. 3 and no other boxes at that point. The idea of the game is for a little kid to be able to find numbers 1 - 25 in that order and if they happen to misclick, nothing will happen or an error will trigger to start over.

I can't seem to implement the logic. I don't know if I have a mistake in my code somewhere.

What I tried so far is basically, when I click a box with #1 in it, I push that value into a `clickedBoxes` array. Then I tried implement different checks, from index checking etc. but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start-btn')
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-btn')
const timer = document.querySelector('.time__countdown')
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid .square');
const seperateSquare = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
let gameStarted = false;
let counter = 60
let timeInterval;

let clickedSquares = []

startBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame)

function startGame() {
  gameStarted = true;

  randomNumber()

  timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--
    if (counter >= 0) {
      timer.innerHTML = `Time left: ${counter}`
    }
  }, 1000)

}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function randomNumber() {
  const numArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
    numArray.push(i)
  }

  numArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)

    squares[i].textContent = numArray[i]
    squares[i].style.fontSize = random + 15 + "px";
    squares[i].style.color = getRandomColor()
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#000000'
    squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      clickedSquares.push(numArray[i])
      console.log(clickedSquares)

      // clickedSquares.map((x,y) => {

      //   if (clickedSquares[0] === 1 && x === 1) {
      //     return squares[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green'
      //   } else if (clickedSquares[1] === 2 && x === 2 && clickedSquares[0] === 1 && x === 1) {

      //   } return squares[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green'


      //   console.log(x)
      //   console.log(clickedSquares[0])

      // })


    })
  }




}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearInterval(timeInterval)
  counter = 60
  timer.innerHTML = `Time left: 60`
  gameStarted = false
  squares.forEach((n) => {
    n.textContent = "";
    n.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  })



})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #ACBFE6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.time {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ACBFE6
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.square-selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="time">
    <p class="time__countdown">Time left: 60</p>
  </div>
  <grid class="grid">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </grid>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start-btn">Start Game</button>
    <button class="btn reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do and what you're having a problem with. One option is to not attach event handlers to any of the squares until you know what numbers are in them. Then, attach the event handler for clicking the square with 1 in it. In that handler, you attach the event handler for the next square in the sequence. That way, nothing happens when clicking any other square. Of course, that's easy to cheat; just click all of the squares until something happens; the only trick is time.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Basically i want to make sure that i can only click on no. 2 if not 1 was clicked and i can't click on another other box. Once no. 1 and 2 have been clicked, i can only click on no. 3 and no other boxes at that point. The idea of the game is for a little kid to be able to find numbers 1 - 25 in that order and if they happen to misclick, nothing will happen or an error will trigger to start over.

Comment: Ok, so my numbers are randomized. Once the loop runs and i know where numbers are visually, how do i attach an event handler to that particular square since they all have the same class. Since they all appear random, i cant give them classes ahead of time to find them later.  Would it be something like square.textContent = 1 ?

Comment: [Edit] your question to clarify it. No one reads comments (except for the author and people who comment). If you follow the path I laid out in my comment, it will work as you describe. You could remove the event handler from the clicked element also, so clicking the same number twice doesn't do anything.

Comment: The event handler itself doesn't need to know anything except what number it is, and how to find the next element in the sequence. I'd add a `data-number` attribute at the same time as you set the text (e.g., `squares[i].dataset.number = numArray[i]`). Then, in the event handler, you can get that value (`var num = +this.dataset.number;`) and then get the next element (`const nextEl = document.querySelector('[data-number="' + (num + 1) + '"]');`) and add the event handler (`nextEl.addEventListener('click', numberClicked);`). Something like that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your working example.
enjoy friend..

```js
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start-btn')
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-btn')
const timer = document.querySelector('.time__countdown')
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid .square');
const seperateSquare = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
let gameStarted = false;
let counter = 60
let timeInterval;

let clickedSquares = []

startBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame)

function startGame() {
  gameStarted = true;

  randomNumber()

  timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--
    if (counter >= 0) {
      timer.innerHTML = `Time left: ${counter}`
    }
  }, 1000)

}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function randomNumber() {
  const numArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
    numArray.push(i)
  }

  numArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)

    squares[i].textContent = numArray[i]
    squares[i].style.fontSize = random + 15 + "px";
    squares[i].style.color = getRandomColor()
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#000000'
    squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {  

if(
   (+clickedSquares[clickedSquares.length - 1] === +(numArray[i] - 1))
   || 
   (+numArray[i] === 1 && clickedSquares.length === 0) 
 ){
  clickedSquares.push(numArray[i]);
  console.log(clickedSquares)
}
else {
  alert("wrong number selected");
}
  })



}
}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearInterval(timeInterval)
  counter = 60
  timer.innerHTML = `Time left: 60`
  gameStarted = false
  squares.forEach((n) => {
    n.textContent = "";
    n.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  })



})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #ACBFE6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.time {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ACBFE6
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.square-selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="time">
    <p class="time__countdown">Time left: 60</p>
  </div>
  <grid class="grid">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </grid>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start-btn">Start Game</button>
    <button class="btn reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That actually works. Can you walk me through your thinking process? Basically you compared index of clickedSquares with numArray. I think my mistake was that i did not account for numArray loop starting at 1 instead of 0 and never specified numArray - 1 when i tried comparing it with clickedSquares index?  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help

```
 squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {  
    console.log(clickedSquares)
    if(clickedSquares[clickedSquares.length - 1] === (numArray[i] - 1) ){
      clickedSquares.push(numArray[i]);
    }
    else {
      alert("wrong number selected");
    }
 })
```

Comment: That does not seem to work.

Comment: have you tried it in your code?

Comment: I tried it and realise that condition is wrong so I submitted another answer , you can check it, it is working fine. check another answer of mine. Thanks